# highlight table row after dynamically adding it

Tags: jquery

looking at how i can highlight a table row after dynamically adding it with jquery
my code seems to be adding the row with no problems, but its not highlighting the correct row

jquery

```
$('#opponents tr:last').after('<tr><td>data</td><td>more data</td></tr>').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

haml/table

```
%table.twelve#opponents
      %thead
        %tr
          %th Name
          %th Manager
      %tbody
        - @opponents.each do |opponent|
          %tr
            %td= opponent.name
            %td.span1
              - if can? :update, @opponent
                .btn-group
                  %button.btn.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown"}
                    %i.icon-pencil
                    Manage
                    %span.caret
                  %ul.dropdown-menu
                    %li= link_to "Edit #{opponent.name}", "#modalOpponent"
                    -if can? :manage, @opponent
                      %li.divider
                      %li= link_to "Delete #{opponent.name}", opponent, :method => :delete, :remote => :true, :confirm => true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would assume that the effect would be applied to what ever `tr:last` was as that is the main selector.

`after()` returns the jQuery object from the original selector `$('#opponents tr:last')` allowing you to continue chaining on to that main selector.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sBg47/) - Using existing code, wrong row is highlighted

---

Try separating the new row into it's own instead and applying the effect to it directly. Similar to this:

```
var $newRow = $('<tr><td>data</td><td>more data</td></tr>');

$('#opponents tr:last').after($newRow);
$newRow.effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DCwJN/) - Working DEMO of above code

---

Comment: I added some DEMO to show-case the difference. When using `$(xxx).after().effect()` the effect is applied to the object selected in the first selector. `after()` does not return the HTML you pass into it, it continues passing on the jQuery object from the original selector. Instead, separate out the new HTML into it's own and apply effect on it directly and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add css in effects like follow:

```
$('#opponents tr:last').after('<tr><td>data</td><td>more data</td></tr>').effect("highlight", {color:'#ff0000'}, 3000);
```