# jquery highlight table row and fade down after a few seconds

Tags: jquery

Supposing I have a table row

```
<tr id="tr_41"><td>stuff in here</td></tr>
```

And using jquery I add something like

```
$("#tr_41").addClass("testbg");
```

testbg is css that just does `.testbg { border: 10px solid blue; }`

What I want to do i when the blue border is applied to the tr_41 row using `$("#tr_41").addClass("testbg");`  is fade it down/off to invisible after a few seconds.

It is for highlighting a last inserted or modified table row after an edit action has taken place and the table is reloaded using ajax

Is this possible?  I have tried jquery fade but the row just ends up dissapearing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
$("#tr_41").toggleClass("testbg").fadeOut(400, function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("testbg").fadeIn(0)
})
```

Please let me know if doesn't. Thanks.

Comment: here is a fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ycgxsr0r/ and for testing I just changed tr and tds to div(s).

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS `keyframes` with the `forwards` attribute for this :

```js
$('div').on('click',function(){
  var that = $(this);
  that.addClass('clicked');
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    that.removeClass('clicked');
  },2000);
});
```

```css
div{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

div.clicked{
  animation: fadeOut 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    0%   {border-color: blue;}
    100% {border-color: black;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I am not using a click event to fire things off.  I am adding to the relevant table row class in the success part of the returned Ajax.  E.g something like $("#tr_41").addClass("testbg");

Comment: I just used a click to show you how it works. Just import the keyframe into your CSS and activate your class whenever you want.

Comment: Ok, so i have done the following CSS this time using the background as red 
 fade down to white but it just stays red when i addClass testbg to my TR

.testbg {
    background-color:red!important;
    animation: fadeOut 2s forwards;
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
        background-color: white !important;
    }

    100% {
        background-color: red !important;
    }
}

Comment: You need to revers your two colors : Red first then white.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that and sadly it still just stays red.  I must be doing something very wrong.  My css is this right now

.testbg {
    background-color:red!important;
    animation: fadeOut 2s forwards;
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
        background-color: red !important;
    }

    100% {
        background-color: white !important;
    }
}

Comment: and i am adding using

$("#tr_41").addClass("testbg");

Comment: Perfect - Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution could be, that you add a second class to the tag when you insert the table row. Although the CSS for the second class would have the `transition` property applied for the border.

Here is an example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tr_41").addClass("testbg");
  $("body").on("click", "#tr_41", function() {
    $("#tr_41").addClass("secondclass");
  });
});
```

```css
.testbg {
  border: 10px solid blue;
}

.secondclass {
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
  border: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="tr_41">
  <td>stuff in here</td>
</span>
```

In my example the event triggers, when you click on the element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Thanks - but again there are no clicks involved once the TR is used addClass to highlight it.  I need to add the class to the relevant TR and it just fades off for example the border effect on its own - is that possible?

Comment: @CraigC take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14687961/7654934). I think it is exactly what you are looking for